# Get memory usage of process in %

Tags: c#

I'd like to get the percentage of memory usage of a process.

This is what I currently have:

```cs
return new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "% Committed Bytes In Use").NextValue();
```

However, this is the RAM usage of my whole computer, not only the process.

When trying to add a string parameter to `PerformanceCounter`, it doesn't work because you apparently can't provide a process name for this counters category.

Comment: _"not only the process"_ - the memory usage of a process is always 100% of the memory usage of that process. Please elaborate on what **exactly** you want to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Memory usage of the current process:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64
```

Total system memory:

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ComputerInfo().TotalPhysicalMemory
```

Multiplying the first one by 100 and dividing the result by the second you get the percentage.